# I can not locate dropdown element which are not select tag

Tags: selenium, testing, cucumber, gherkin

I can not locate dropdown element in Selnium which are not select tag. I want to select from the options that opens after clicking.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Select class for selecting the dropdown. You have to click on dropdown item. Then use below xpath to click on dropdown element

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xPath("dropdownPath"));
dropdown.click(); 
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement dropdownItem = driver.findElement(By.xPath("//button[text()='Mr.']"));
dropdownItem.click();
```